# Mysql Multiple Database Query Tool

Tags: mysql, sql

I run an application where each user gets there own database and often times there is schema migrations.

I wrote a PHP script that handles running multiple queries across databases, but I am looking for a more robust tool, that could allow me to compare schemas, run validations, rollbacks. Is there a tool like this that exists?

Comment: Maybe duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602158/how-decently-track-the-database-structure-modification-by-svn

Comment: @OMG the tools like LiquiBase may accomplish the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use [Redgate](http://www.red-gate.com/) and love it. It can be scripted or run manually. It will compare schema or data.